# Java JList scroll to selected item

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jlist

I have a `JList` with a lot of items in it, of which one is selected. I would like to scroll to the selected item in this `JList`, so the user can quickly see which item is selected.

How can I do this?

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four", /* AND A LOT MORE */};
JList dataList = new JList(data);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataList);
```

Comment: To make sure it is always visible you can override the setSelectedIndex method and call the Sbodd's method from there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This should do it:

```
dataList.ensureIndexIsVisible(dataList.getSelectedIndex());
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `ensureIndexIsVisible` method

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#ensureIndexIsVisible(int)

> Scrolls the list within an enclosing
>   viewport to make the specified cell
>   completely visible. This calls
>   scrollRectToVisible with the bounds of
>   the specified cell. For this method to
>   work, the JList must be within a
>   JViewport.

Answer (score 12):

Or, if multi-selection is enabled :

```
dataList.scrollRectToVisible(
        dataList.getCellBounds(
            dataList.getMinSelectionIndex(), 
            dataList.getMaxSelectionIndex()
        )
);
```

Comment: its dataList.getMinSelectionIndex()
however, the answer is still useful for me :)