# How to set the desired position scrollpane?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

`Method  sp.setVvalue(app.spvalue.intValue());` doesn't scroll vbox to desired position.

```
            mvPane = new VBox();
            mvPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff;");
            GetPlayList(app,root);

            sp = new ScrollPane();
            sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
            sp.setContent(mvPane);
            sp.setVvalue(40);
            setCenter(sp);
            sp.getVvalue();
```

Function GetPlayList adds many labels.

Comment: Consider selecting the item and then following the advice here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543705/java-jlist-scroll-to-selected-item>

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to consider selecting the item?

Comment: I guess you are mentioning JavaFX scrollpane control so removed "jscrollpane" tag. What does the app.spvalue refer to? How are you setting that variable? Provide a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about JavaFX 2.0, and its scrollPane, then Hvalue and Vvalue properties are working well, but the matter, look like, that their values are doubles from range [0.0 .. 1.0], so, when you set int value, it will not work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem - I noticed that if you try to do `yourScrollPane.setVvalue()` before doing `yourStage.show()`, it will NOT scroll. However, it will work if `sp.setVvalue()` is executed *after* the stage is already shown. Not sure if that's a bug in ScrollPane or intended behavior. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the issue surely was the number 40, as only values between 0 and 1 are allowed. However stumbled across this question while having the same issue for a different reason.
Found out that it is important that setHvalue() and setVvalue are executed only on the JFX thread (aka with Platform.runlater). Otherwise the position is not visibly updated until a user-driven scroll-event is initiated!